# QLabel isn't displayed if not a member

Tags: c++, qt

I have a class which displays QLabel with some text in QGridLayout. When QLabel is a class member, everything is ok, but when it is not, it isn't displayed in grid.

QLabel is not a member and is created in the constructor.

```
class Account : public QWidget
    {
    private:
       //QLabel lab;
        QGridLayout * grid;
          public:
        Account(QWidget * parent=0);

    public slots:
        void spend(int);
        void update();

    };
```

.cpp

```
#include <QLabel>
    #include <QLineEdit>
    #include <QTextStream>
#include <QFileInfo>
#include <vector>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <iostream>

Account::Account(QWidget * parent) : QWidget(parent)
{

    grid=new QGridLayout(this);
    QLabel lab;
    lab.setText("RFD");
    grid->addWidget(&lab,0,0); //is not displayed
}
```

QLabel is a member:

```
  class Account : public QWidget
    {
    private:
       QLabel lab;
        QGridLayout * grid;
          public:
        Account(QWidget * parent=0);

    public slots:
        void spend(int);
        void update();

    };
```

.cpp

```
#include <QLabel>
    #include <QLineEdit>
    #include <QTextStream>
    #include <QFileInfo>
    #include <vector>
    #include <QGridLayout>
    #include <iostream>

    Account::Account(QWidget * parent) : QWidget(parent)
    {

        grid=new QGridLayout(this);
        lab.setText("RFD");
        grid->addWidget(&lab,0,0); //is displayed
    }
```

WHy is it so?

Comment: If you create lab on the stack, it's destroyed right away at the end of the block (ie end of the ctor). You must create it on the heap and/or make it a member

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because when you declare QLabel in your constructor it is only a local variable, therefore it falls out-of-scope at the end of the function (see my comments below):

```
{
    grid=new QGridLayout(this);
    QLabel lab; // created here
    lab.setText("RFD");
    grid->addWidget(&lab,0,0); //is not displayed
} // destroyed here as the variable is out of scope
```

**note**

If you want to create it in your constructor then make it a pointer and new it - you will still need to keep track of this pointer, either as a member variable or pass the pointer to some other function / class to take care of it... (i.e. to delete it when you are finished with it...

Further - addWidget() takes a pointer, so it might handle the destruction of it itself - so you could probably do:

```
{
    grid=new QGridLayout(this);
    QLabel *pLab = new QLabel(this);
    lab.setText("RFD");
    grid->addWidget(pLab,0,0); //is not displayed
}
```

Comment: Thank you! `grid=new QGridLayout(this);`
    `QLabel * lab=new QLabel;`
    `lab->setText("RFD");`
    `grid->addWidget(lab,0,0);`
works. But I once heard that Qt takes care of the heap memory itself, isn't it so? Or in this case the `* lab` pointer will be deleted, but its heap memory will remain untouched?

Comment: Yes I believe you are right that Qt will take care of it... but it always feels like a leakk - from my pure c++ background :o

Comment: @parsecer: If you give a QLabel a parent, like it is done in `new QLabel(this)`, Qt will clean it up for you if `this` is destroyed. See also https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#setParent in case you need to do this explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

`QLabel lab;` is a local variable that lives until the end of the function and then gets automatically destroyed, so the label you want displayed doesn't actually exist anymore when you want to display it.

Furthermore Qt has a <s>broken</s> unconventional [memory model](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html) that requires you to `new` up the `QLabel` and then pass an owning raw pointer to the function which Qt will automatically `delete` later when the parent gets removed. <s>If you `delete` it manually you get a double `delete` (one from you and one from Qt) which usually results in a crash.</s> Manually `delete`ing an object will automatically detach it from the parent, so you don't get a double `delete`.

The way Qt wants you to do it is

```
QLabel *lab = new QLabel;
lab->setText("RFD");
grid->addWidget(lab,0,0);
```

While this looks like a memory leak, it isn't, due to Qt's memory model.

Comment: This is not completely true. As stated in the link you provided, when you delete an object yourself before the parent, you won't get a double delete. When objects are destroyed, they are removed from the parent. You only get a double delete when you try to delete something yourself after it has been already destroyed by the parent. It also doesn't force you to use `new`. You just have to take care of the definition order if you don't use `new`. But other than that, your answer is correct.

Comment: @thuga Can you go into more detail? Qt cannot know if an object has been deleted by you or not. What you *can* do it take back ownership from Qt and then manually delete. You also can give Qt a pointer not created by `new` and take back ownership before the parent disappears, not sure if that is maintainable.

Comment: When the object is destroyed, it is removed from the parent. The parent won't try to destroy it again. The link you provided states: *You can also delete child objects yourself, and they will remove themselves from their parents*. So as long as children are destroyed before the parent, you don't have to worry about double deletion.

Comment: @thuga Ah, the QObjects have a pointer to their parent and detach themselves automatically. Interesting, thanks.